# S3 NextContinuationToken / ContinuationToken: does it expire?

Tags: amazon-s3, pagination

Using the [ListObjectsV2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html#API_ListObjectsV2_RequestSyntax) API, is there any time limit on when the returned `NextContinuationToken` can be used? Can I use it an hour after it was returned? A week? A year?

Comment: yeah, I think it will never expire.

Comment: @jellycsc Feel free to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No documentation online mentioned the expiration of the NextContinuationToken. So I would assume it will never expire.